# Error trying to read properties file from WEB-INF directory in Spring

Tags: java, spring

In my Java service, i'm trying to read the properties file as below

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.site.xxx.*" })
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@Service("someService")
public class SomeService {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    ...
}
```

And then in one of my methods, I do

```
String closeDate = env.getProperty("close.date");
```

There are 2 problems here either of which I could work with as a solution.

1> This works in a way that it does read the file if my application.properties file is in the classpath. I put it under src/main/resources and it reads the file BUT after I deploy the change, if I change the date inside this property file, it still shows me the first date which was entered when the code was compiled. So the reading part works but it doesn't change when I change the file contents.

2> If I change the contents of the following line

```
@PropertySource("classpath:WEB-INF/application.properties")
```

and if I place the file under my WEB-INF directory, even though the file is present, it says File Not Found.

I would very much prefer #2 to work but if there is no way that it can work (which I don't think), I can work with #1 as long as it behaves like a property file.

Comment: With Option(1), if you change the property and restart your server, does it work fine?

Comment: I haven't tried it. Not sure if the server will overwrite the value?

Comment: No it doesn't override

Comment: In any case, restarting the server might not be an option for me because this is going to go into a production environment. Do property file changes usually warrant a server restart? I thought no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Spring loads the property files during the container startup**, so whenever you change the property inside `application.properties`, you need to restart your server. So, that might be a reason your option(1) is not working.

If you wanted to work with option(2), you can configure the `PropertySource` with `file:` (not `classpath:`) as shown below and you need to set `myproject.home` (or any other name of your choice) as the environment (OS) or system variable.

```
@PropertySource("file:${myproject.home}/WEB-INF/application.properties")
```

> Do property file changes usually warrant a server restart?

Yes, they need a container restart.

Comment: I tried it. A restart is not overwriting the file so I should be good.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve #2 without touching any system or environment variables? I would think it should be fairly straight forward to get the location of WEB-INF which is in the same context of this file?

Comment: You can pass as commandline argument as well while starting Springboot

Comment: I'm not using SpringBoot unfortunately.